# Display a number in the style of Stackoverflow reputation

Tags: ruby, formatting, numbers

My reputation appears as **2,606**.

- If I had more, it would look like **15.4k**.
- If I had *a lot* more, it would look like **264k**

What's the best way to display a number in this format using Ruby?

Comment: Does ruby have `if`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do with this simple method:

```
class Integer
  def pretty_str
    case
    when self < 1000
      to_s
    when self < 10000
      to_s.insert(1, ",")
    when self < 100000
      ("%.1fk" % (self / 1000.0)).sub(".0", "")
    else
      (self / 1000).pretty_str << "k"
    end
  end
end

123.pretty_str       #=> "123"
1234.pretty_str      #=> "1,234"
12345.pretty_str     #=> "12.3k"
123456.pretty_str    #=> "123k"
1234567.pretty_str   #=> "1.234k"
12345678.pretty_str  #=> "12.3kk"
```

Comment: +1, but "1234" should go to "1,234" (I'm going to hold you up for the fix ;-)

Comment: Also, I think 1000-9999 is in "x,xxx" format. See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/54123 for ",".

Comment: Thanks by the sugestions. All fixed.

Comment: There's an extra 'k' here: `1234567.pretty_str => "1,234k"`

Comment: Also, `10000.pretty_str` should be `10k` (not `10.0k`). Cleaner, no?

Comment: Edited again. But what is wrong with `1234567.pretty_str => "1,234k"`? Where is the extra "k"?

Comment: Never seen such use of `case` _OO

Comment: @LBg: that's my bad; there is no extra 'k'

Answer (score 2):

I just installed ruby and this is my first attempt with the language. May be it's very un-rubyesque

```
def reputation(x)
  if x >= 100000
    "%dk" % (x / 1000)
  elsif x >= 10000
    "%.1fk" % (x / 1000.0)
  elsif x >= 1000
    "%d" % (x/1000) + ",%03d" % (x%1000)
  else
    "%d" % x
  end
end

puts reputation(999)    # --> 999
puts reputation(1000)   # --> 1,000
puts reputation(1234)   # --> 1,234
puts reputation(9999)   # --> 9,999
puts reputation(10000)  # --> 10.0k
puts reputation(12345)  # --> 12,3k
puts reputation(123456) # --> 123k
```

EDIT: Removed `return`s and added comma for thousands

Comment: +1 but... did you know that `if/elsif/else` is *just an expression* in ruby and that methods return the value of their last expression by default? (hint: no need to use `return` at all there -- or at least not more than once -- see LBg's answer). Also, 1234 should go to "1,234" :-)

Comment: Actually in my first try was identical but without `return`, but didn't work. I tried with return (because I saw emacs highlighted it) and worked. Indeed I retried now and works even without return... I did something wrong for sure...

Comment: Now, what about for 1234000? :) (Mr. Skeet will be there soon enough :-/)

Comment: I think `reputation(10000)` should be `10k` (not `10.0k`). Cleaner, no?

Comment: @Horace Loeb: `10k` and `10.0k` are not the same thing (watch out especially for physics exams, when I was at university confusing them could have mean failing a session).

Comment: I agree that they're different, I just don't think the users of my application care about the difference (I'm representing point values, so it's all make believe anyway)